# Microsoft SQL Server Query Result with PyQt5 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtsql

everyone
I'm a Python Beginner.
I'm trying to use Microsoft SQL Server Query Result with PyQt5 in Python.
I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.
I would like to query result with PyQt5 in Python.
It looks like this, is there something wrong ?

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys

SERVER = '192.168.0.250:1433'
DATABASE = 'openfire'
USERNAME = 'lester'
PASSWORD = '123456'

def createConnection():
connString = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};'\
            f'SERVER={SERVER};'\
            f'DATABASE={DATABASE};'\
            f'USERNAME={USERNAME};'\
            f'PASSWORD={PASSWORD}'

global db
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
db.setDatabaseName('connString')

if db.open():
    print('connect to SQL Server successfully')
    return True
else:
    print('connection failed')
    return False

def displayData(sqlStatement):
    print('processing query...')
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare(sqlStatement)
    qry.exec()

model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery(qry)

view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
return view

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

if createConnection():
    SQL_STATEMENT = 'SELECT * FROM ofuser'
    dataView = displayData(SQL_STATEMENT)
    dataView.show()

app.exit()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

1433 is your PORT.

```
SERVER = '192.168.0.250'
PORT = '1433'
DATABASE = 'openfire'
USERNAME = 'lester'
PASSWORD = '123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

I modifyed some code by myself.
It's successful now.

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys

SERVER = '192.168.0.253,1433'
DATABASE = 'openfire'
USERNAME = 'lester'
PASSWORD = '123456'

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
db.setDatabaseName(f'Driver={{SQL SERVER}}; Server={SERVER}; Database={DATABASE}; UID={USERNAME}; PWD={PASSWORD}')
db.open()

def displayData(sqlStatement):
    print('processing query...')
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare(sqlStatement)
    qry.exec()

    model = QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery(qry)

    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    return view

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    SQL_STATEMENT = 'SELECT * FROM ofuser'
    dataView = displayData(SQL_STATEMENT)
    dataView.show()
    app.exit()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```